FEM - correct solution at nodes using cubic shape functions for a 4th degree displacement function
I'm reading my structural analysis professor's notes and I found this passage, which I don't really understand.
Context: we're trying to find the displacements of a structure using FEM. We use beam elements with 2 nodes and 3 degrees of freedom at each node: axial displacement w, transverse displacement v, rotation phi. If the beam is only subjected to forces and moments at the nodes, the solution will be exact because the bending moment will be at most linear, so the transverse displacement v will be at most cubic.
My professor then goes on to say that even with distributed loads (and thus a 4th degree transverse displacement function) the solution at the nodes will still be exact if we use cubic shape functions. I don't understand how that is possible. If we use a cubic polynomial, the equivalent nodal loads will be different, right? How can the solution be exact?

I will try to explain this just on a simple 2 node truss element with axial stiffness $k$ in 1D space. Simplest static system of equations for nodal forces and displacements for such element is:
$$\left[\begin{matrix} k & -k \\ -k & k \end{matrix}\right]\cdot \left[\begin{matrix} u_i \\ u_j \end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix} F_i \\ F_j \end{matrix}\right]$$
Lets say you want to apply distributed axial load $Q(x)$ [N/m] on such element. In FEA, you cannot use such load directly, but you need to convert it into equivalent nodal forces. Preferably, these equivalent forces should have the same effect on the element as the distributed load.
The first condition is that sum of the nodal forces (both positive in the $x$ direction) should be the same as integral of the distributed load across the length of the element:
$$F_i + F_j = \int\limits_0^L Q(x) dx$$
The second condition comes from deformation. You can express, how much should your distributed axial force elongate the element. The axial force pulling at arbitrary $x$ is given by integral of $Q(x)$:
$$N(x) = \int\limits_0^x Q(x) dx$$
The total elongation is then given by integral of this force divided by section stiffness ($E$ is Young's modulus and $A$ is section area), which is basically integral of axial strain:
$$\delta = \int\limits_0^L\frac{N(x)}{E(x)A(x)} dx$$
You can express this elongation also using the nodal forces and axial stiffness $k$ of the element:
$$\delta = \frac{1}{k}\cdot \left(-F_i + F_j\right)$$
Now you have 2 equations with 2 unknowns:
$$\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]\cdot \left[\begin{matrix} F_i \\ F_j \end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix} \int\limits_0^L Q(x) dx \\ k\cdot \int\limits_0^L\frac{N(x)}{E(x)A(x)} dx \end{matrix}\right]$$
As you can see, the base functions were not even mentioned in this derivation, but the simplest ones, i.e. linear for axial displacement can be assumed. The thing is that in the end, FEA just solves forces and displacements at the nodes. So even the most complex load has to be converted to bunch of numbers. After the solution is obtained, you can even express the displacements using the original loads at individual elements.
Also the variability of section and material along the element can be included. Even though the element works with axial stiffness $k$, which could be based on mean values of Young's modulus and section area, actual distribution of Young's modulus and section area is used in calculating of the equivalent nodal forces.
